# Google Charts & JQuery Mobile: setOnLoadCallback and ajax transitions?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, google-visualization

I have two pages:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7997532/Spentrax/analyze.html

is a page with a number of charts and such created using the google charts api, rendering some static dummy data.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7997532/Spentrax/debts.html

is just another random page.

I have found that if you go to `analyze.html` directly, the charts are rendered. If I go to `debts.html` and then click on the link to `analyze.html`, the charts are not rendered. I have concluded that this is because the functions given to `setOnLoadCallback()` (let's call them, collectively, `render()`) are not fired off when JQuery Mobile's magic ajax transitions mutate `debts.html` into `analyze.html`. If I manually fire off `render()` later using the console, the charts are indeed rendered perfectly.

The question is, what can be done about this? I obviously need to somehow get `render()` to fire immediately if I Ajax transition from `debts.html` to `analyze.html`, but *not* to fire immediately and be added to the `setOnloadCallback()` in the case where I go to `analyze.html` directly. I can think of many hacky solutions with javascript reading the URL and making decisions based on that, but what's the proper way to do these things?